# I need to store each entered line into the same array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I need to store multiple lines of input into the same array. The loop has to continue storing each new line into the array until a sentinel value is typed in. So far, I have this code:

```
     while(!students.equals("zzzz") && !students.equals("ZZZZ")){
        students = br.readLine();
        studentInfo = students.split("\\n");

        }
        System.out.println (studentInfo[0]);
```

All this does when I type the sentinel value (either ZZZZ or zzzz) is print out zzzz at the end because it stores the sentinel value into the first array location. What am I missing? Id like to be able to type any number of lines, and access each one of those lines and manipulate the string by calling on it (studentInfo[5] or studentInfo[55]). Please help

Comment: must you use an array? Considering the number of lines is a variable.

Comment: Use a List, specifically an ArrayList. When you're done, you can use the toArray() method of ArrayList.

Comment: I'm not sure how else I can store each line of input and use it later without an array. I need to be able to look up the information for student 30 (array value 29) after all the information is entered and then manipulate that string input and compare it to another string

Comment: you can also use !students.equalsIgnoreCase("zzzz")

Comment: The problem you are facing is that you have define somewhere `String[] studentInfo` and you override that variable in each iteration of your while loop. Therefore in the end you have the sentinel in it.

Comment: yes exactly hotzst but I'm not sure how to retain the original inputs without overriding them and still looping.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, `br.readLine()` will not return anything with a newline character, so this code:

```
students = br.readLine();
studentInfo = students.split("\\n");
```

will always result in `studentInfo` being an array of size 1, whose first (and only) element is whatever is in `students`.

Further, you are *replacing* `studentInfo` every loop, so it always has the *last* line entered, which logically must be `"zzzz"` or `"ZZZZ"`.

To fix the problem, you should use a `List`, which can grow in size automatically (basically you should avoid using arrays).

Try this:

```
List<String> studentInfo = new LinkedList<>();
String student = "";

while (!student.equalsIgnoreCase("zzzz")) {
    student = br.readLine();
    if (!student.equalsIgnoreCase("zzzz"))
        studentInfo.add(student);
}

System.out.println (studentInfo);
```

The `while` loop is a little clumsy, because the `student` variable must be declared outside the loop (even though it's only needed *in* the loop) and the condition must be repeated (otherwise your data will contain the terminating signal value).

It can be expressed better as a `for` loop:

```
for (String student = br.readLine(); !student.equalsIgnoreCase("zzzz"); student = br.readLine())
        studentInfo.add(student);
```

Note also the use of `equalsIgnoreCase()` for the string comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I have made slight changes to your code and added comments on how this can be done:

```
List<String> studentInfo = new ArrayList<>(); //use arraylist since you don't know how many students you are expecting
//read the first line
String line = ""; //add line reading logic e.g. br.readLine();
while(!line.equalsIgnoreCase("zzzz")){ //check for your sentinel value
    line = br.readLine(); //read other lines
    //you can add an if statment to avoid adding zzzz to the list
    studentInfo.add(students);
}
System.out.println("Total students in list is: " + studentInfo.size());

System.out.println (studentInfo); //print all students in list
System.out.println (studentInfo.get(29)); //print student 30
```